# How to remove blur effect from UIProgressView / make progressView's background complete transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

**Simple Requirement:** A progress view with transparent background with no blur effect.

1. **1st image:** Expected progress view
2. **2nd image:** That's how it currently looks
3. **3rd image:** Visual effect applied by apple on UIProgressView

**Issue**: UIVisualEffect is interfering with requirement.

**Setup**: `progressTintColor` is set to **white** and `trackTintColor` to **white with 30% opacity.**

I have tried removing `UIVisualEffect` by looping through subviews and removing subview which is UIVisualEffectView but no luck!!!

```
for subview in blurView.subviews {
  if subview is UIVisualEffectView {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

[image: Expected progress view with transparent background]

[image: Output]

[image: VisualEffect applied by apple]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `UIProgressView` does **not** have a blur / visual effect view. You're either using a custom progress view or doing something else that's putting it there.

Comment: Have you found any solution here, I am also looking for same.

Comment: @swapnil Not really. Instead, I created custom progress view to support the design.